# Responsive site: navbar is shrinking the whole appearence

Tags: android, html, ios, responsive-design

I built a responsive website (http://www.cjkrause.de/borgo-v2) which behaves strangely on both android and ios smartphone devices. I have a navigation bar that seems to force the browser to shrink the whole site in order to fit it into the window. But there is no width set on this bar, so it should just rearrange its content to fit it on the screen.

I already have this in my header section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

See here how it shows on my android phone:
[android appearence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C9u9.png)

On a desktop browser, even in responsive emulation, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if the problem is with your map towards the bottom of the home page.

It's in an iframe with a hard coded width of 600px, so it doesn't scale down on smaller viewports and causes other elements on your page to expand.

Comment: Oh my - obviously. I now used the method from https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/ to make my iframe responsive. Thank you.